# Doctrine query builder select count onetomany entities

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, query-builder

I have Group and User entities. They are associated through GroupUser entity - which is manytomany entity with extra fields like status.

```
Class Group

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="GroupUser", mappedBy="group")
 */
private $groupUsers;

Class User

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="GroupUser", mappedBy="user")
 */
private $userGroups;


Class GroupUser

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="userGroups", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Group", inversedBy="groupUsers", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $group;
```

How to get list of groups which User has joined with number of users in each group with QueryBuilder

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('group')
        ->select('group.id', 'group.name', 'COUNT(groupUser.user) as membersCount')
        ->join('group.groupUsers', 'groupUser')
        ->where('groupUser.user = :userId')
        ->andWhere('groupUser.status = :status')
        ->addGroupBy('groupUser.group')
        ->setParameter('userId', $user->getId())
        ->setParameter('status', $status);

    $results = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

This query return membersCount as 1 for all groups even if there are more than one member. How to change query to get correct number of members for each group?

Comment: Well, you are having a `->where('groupUser.user = :userId')` in there, so you're only selecting rows of that user - hence the COUNT is 1.

Comment: @ccKep yeah I guessed that it's a problem. but on the other hand I need groups for  that particular user. Is there way to get number of users ignoring that where clause

Comment: Add a 2nd join on the same field (with another alias) and use the COUNT and groupBy on that one.